android Studio gradle & AGP upgrade issue
I use Android studio Flamingo. I have my project set with Gradle 6.5 and gradle plugin 4.2.2 . After new google console changes, min target to upload app to console is 34. Thus , I have to use AGP 7.4.2 and Gradle 7.5  (minimum requiremnt) in order to set target version to 34. I have updated gradle.wraper.properties to :
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10-bin.zip

But , i now get new errors in after Gradle sync, that was not present in old gradle : these errors are :
A problem occurred configuring root project 'VetmoRestAdmin'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.5/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.5.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.5/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.5.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/jfrog/bintray/gradle/gradle-bintray-plugin/1.8.5/gradle-bintray-plugin-1.8.5.pom
     Required by:
         root project :
   > Could not find com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.9.2/bintray-release-0.9.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.9.2/bintray-release-0.9.2.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/novoda/bintray-release/0.9.2/bintray-release-0.9.2.pom
     Required by:
         root project :

Possible solution:
 - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

My build.gradle(Project) file is :
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

apply plugin: 'com.novoda.bintray-release'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        //maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        //maven {  url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/") } // update grade to google console zico
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository


    }
    dependencies {
       
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
       
        classpath("com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.5") // update grade to google console zico : https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.jfrog.bintray
        classpath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.9.2' // update grade to google console zico : https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release



        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
       //xxxxclasspath 'com.novoda:bintray-release:0.8.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        flatDir {            // to include PAYMOB libraryt to project
            dirs("libs")
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' } // mandatory for table library .... https://github.com/huangyanbin/smartTable
        //maven {  url "https://repo.eclipse.org/content/repositories/paho-snapshots/" }  
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
      
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

How to resolve these issues to be able to build project.
Thanks...
